# Marker Clustering in Google maps: how to set custom label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am trying to implement the cluster marker where each of my marker has some data associated with it. I have made a marker cluster using **js-markerclusterer** library. I would like to get the selected markers into my cluster, where I can make some internal calculations to that marker and make a custom label to the marker cluster. The code for the making the marker cluster is of follows:

```
const markerCluster =  new MarkerClusterer({ map: this.map, markers: this.markersArray, renderer});

const renderer = {
        render: ({ count, position }) => {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            label: { text: String(sumCount), color: "white", fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: "500" },
            icon: {url:`assets/images/red_cluster.svg`} ,
            position,
            // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
            zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX)
          })
        }
};
```

How do I get access to the selected markers only in the **render** object? Something like this:
`const sumCount = Sum_of_Selected_marker_only`

Comment: It is not particularly clear what your question actually is or where the problem lies. Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-markerclusterer/interfaces/Renderer.html#render), the `renderer` accepts the two attributes: Cluster and Stats. You can use the renderer the following way

A cluster object:

```
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map: this.map, markers: this.markersArray, renderer: clusterRenderer })
```

The clusterRenderer:

```
  const clusterRenderer = {
    render: (cluster, stats) => {
      // Access to the cluster's attributes, check all available in the doc
      const { markers, position, count, ... } = cluster;
      // Access to the stats' attributes if you need it
      // const { clusters, ... } = stats;

      // Use data from markers to create a new label
      const markerLabel = calculateClusterlabel(markers);

      return new google.maps.Marker({
        label: {
          text: markerLabel,
        },
        position: position,

        zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
      });
    },
  };
```

In most cases, you will use only the marker's label:

```
const calculateClusterlabel = (markers) => {
  markers.map((marker) => Number(marker.getLabel())
         .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```